# Blank ImageView since API 23 (but only for large photos)

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Yesterday I updated my testing device to Android 6.0, minimum SDK version in my app is 23 also. A few days ago I wrote a function displaying images (as ImageView) taken by camera or picked from gallery. Here's a fragment:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showThumbnail);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

try {
    Bitmap bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    URIToSend = selectedImage;

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.main_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And here's a piece of my XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/showThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/suggest_attachedpreview" />
```

Everything worked fine till minimum API raise. Now ImageView height after picking an image is higher, but nothing is shown. There's just a blank space like image was transparent. However I noticed that images equal to 9 Mpix or lower are displayed perfectly... Only larger aren't. Does anyone have any clue how to fix this problem?

**EDIT:** Normally my ImageView is marked as gone - after taking a picture or picking an image from gallery it becomes visible. And even after picking a large image it becomes visible - but there's just a blank space inside.

Comment: My guess is that `getBitmap()` is returning `null`. Where exactly is `selectedImage` coming from?

Comment: It isn't null - my testing Toast shows some numbers always, even if image is blank. Also I edited my original post.